# Jest Received: serializes to the same string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

In jest for some reason you get something like

```
expected: "test"
received: serializes to the same string
```

if you do .toContainEqual

```
expected: "test"
received: "test"
```

this seems to only occur when using mongoose with jest, but I think the issue has to do with uriEncoding and decoding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're testing the response from a request then try

```
expected = decodeURI(encodeURI("test"))
result = [...] // equals "test"

expect(result).toEqual(expected)
```

This may also work but sometimes has issues because of JSON string parsing

```
expected = <some object>
result = <object that serializes to the same string>
expect(result.toString()).toEqual(expect.toString())
```

If you're only comparing the result of a document versus an object or output from an aggregation then try

```
expect(result).toEqual(expected)
```